# Efficient creation of a sequence of sets from values and thresholds

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, performance

Given a shortish sequence of thresholds ordered ascendantly and numerous values (unordered).

Wanted result is a sequence of `set`s, first one containing all distinct values below the lowest/first threshold; next values not below lowest threshold, but below 2nd threshold, if any; and so on 'til last threshold; finally all values not below highest threshold.

There are similar questions about `dict`s (pointers to *helpful* solutions there welcome, too),
suggestions amounting to

```
from itertools import pairwise

def partition(values, thresholds):
    """ Partition values into a list of sets 
        with values in right-open intervals specified by thresholds.
    """
    return [ { v for v in values if v < thresholds[0] }
       ] + [ { v for v in values if lo <= v < hi }
                                for lo, hi in tuple(pairwise(thresholds))
       ] + [ { v for v in values if thresholds[-1] <= v } ]
```

This "iterates" `values` `len(thresholds)+1` times.

How to efficiently create a sequence of `set`s partitioning *values* according to *thresholds*?

I failed to find something helpful SciPy/NumPy.
Using `numpy.digitize()` to index an array of `add()` members was in the ball park of [`partition_Kelly3b()`](/a/76248126/3789665) for non-trivial values *and* thresholds.

Comment: Please show an example and provide code to generate realistic input.

Comment: @SoofGolan: thresholds/bin boundaries are ordered, but not the items.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sorry for not providing a helpful input model, but the problem where I was dissatisfied with what I used (3 thresholds, hand crafted decision tree) wasn't mine. I don't remember an instance where I did know something spectacular about the input, but think most were single threshold (which contributes to liking Kelly3). In said 3rd-party problem there were advantages to having the *n* items ordered in subsequent processing so the "cross-over" from the O(*n*log*n*) growth I expect with sorting will be at even higher values of *n*. I wanted to keep this question (and answers) generic.

Comment: I couldn't convince myself to try out `more_itertools.bucket()`.

Comment: I don't have time to answer but doesn't [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) do what you want? Followed by putting the values and indices into a `collections.defaultdict(set)`

Comment: @Homer512 From the same docs: *[np.digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) is implemented in terms of np.searchsorted* - I don't expect significant differences. (And no, it does not do what I want - using the result to index/key something useful does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test results of various solutions:

```
10000 values and 3 thresholds:
  0.83 ± 0.00 ms  partition_Kelly4
  0.83 ± 0.00 ms  partition_Kelly4c
  0.83 ± 0.01 ms  partition_Kelly4a
  1.42 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly3b
  1.55 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly3
  1.76 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly2
  1.93 ± 0.00 ms  partition_Kelly4b
  2.04 ± 0.01 ms  partition_Kelly
  2.55 ± 0.03 ms  partition_original

10000 values and 10 thresholds:
  0.86 ± 0.01 ms  partition_Kelly4a
  0.87 ± 0.01 ms  partition_Kelly4c
  0.88 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly4
  1.98 ± 0.03 ms  partition_Kelly4b
  2.03 ± 0.03 ms  partition_Kelly3b
  2.06 ± 0.05 ms  partition_Kelly2
  2.22 ± 0.05 ms  partition_Kelly3
  2.52 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly
  6.19 ± 0.19 ms  partition_original

10000 values and 100 thresholds:
  0.94 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly4a
  0.97 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly4
  0.99 ± 0.02 ms  partition_Kelly4c
  2.05 ± 0.03 ms  partition_Kelly4b
  2.62 ± 0.17 ms  partition_Kelly2
  3.41 ± 0.05 ms  partition_Kelly
  3.58 ± 0.33 ms  partition_Kelly3b
  3.91 ± 0.25 ms  partition_Kelly3
 60.49 ± 10.98 ms  partition_original

Wrong:
  partition_dankal444
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=3VjNbuM2EL771jeYpgdLjuLYjlMsjPUT9NJbD4IgyBYZ0ZZFQaQTB0EepOhlL-19X6GP0afpkNQPadmBsbtBi_UhjobD-flm5hPpP_4qn2XGi0-f_txLevPhnx9-pxXfAZOkkpznAtiu5JWEMmHVExNkUD9XSZHy3UArr1C-lo2meQrq7zgnVBo1yXakNUcqGq_5vkA_kAi9ZrSETCQTkq1b1zuSFAHKU_I4GAxSQjGYSjLJeBHzij2wIsm9xyTfExGAzCoiMp6nwl8MAD9XV1fwa6MPRg1YITkkkKMj4BQEkQK0tvo8MZl1ioAeMnnDS1KobaTCFQGiJGtGGUlh9Wz5HDcu9XdF5L4qIIQXeATKK_zLuhAoPn609oaTCF6bICK4Pr8v5_BxqXdnrNty9qMs5DxQymhG7suceE05PQsv_yLnVsA308gE8gpRrzK_kDx_Pl8WfIQlhIi852s3sQ6uVYsarXFSIvSppzVNiEdRLVoEGJo0bWflFcBjm5kyGLJonKSpV0vrIuHC6RRm75yDkhkP_vsmcnc-EUf7vJqOjELBpbW2cPqvaXkrq8jJKieF3XNwewuzVqFdQEWrz1hnIlM2wu4ZRwGfDxrOg9uoB3u6ANcz1tThYAVVR9ylr0bFcr5gkY_z0K1nzFln19NF5FSgU7VQcOA8U6DVd1ShGuovLNTXVmgcx4LkNI7fqVTz8yWo81qCwHcXSW3Dvs0aJj8F1qQlhA4Fh0e6Am5aXtDv1X4UDkHYtGM0Q7bYRB3Ra_ebUyzVqkf-ZewyT_6vkATA_jtU3hjpY1RqRL7nHllfSnB4CKykOvPx8luxXKhtLpTJ6Nsy3gUdaOVjo3_MQUZr8za7bfq42Mx2wbAduZ0EGoGL2C9Nim2Sz-dvEKBzDdASfbzuH5TwCvFAvGPwr2GK5enOSMrNqbMeGotZemixH9slcA5NaqNv7xNhvbk-P3UKNTZKB1On-2KtA-_fN4Lj3u4JZj3JXV-y6onmfUnSF53Ytw5OlSkaPFW8eFDtoMA35ZRESA-vVNsAEy5JIuvKlRVecNTCsG4ivOMNtdrQmrOhgUpO1EDgtU1Z1QL8X6H1QhfIXLp4VBVOo_jaDrm63wmPWqNsmkPCCKbkznCcPhib_tVmQxr54eI-6h0K6PBFXQ89id3383hGX-Hvz_Ci74paNteynYBh11JW8znpO9Nj7rfjdcbZmgjPqBc4Hdtl4ffJQaeg0PPY9fjev91iNoXpdda521rEQw6lujQvkcYKgl98tVHH_c62C6BLb7LD3mU9sc_VGj01nq6FGtaG0I01uAHp6iHP1pEyoUN1A3EyMe6ddZKjgTqsH5e1at-EblI9jNQCQOUdLiIFLT2CQ8Vl3gAo0bstzqBW-2htrBp5XurOs2pt2r3pxwAonhqLZEfiuO5oo-D_1GEzwRU9PdPJaISjiiM9naDQlk2RTz_0ZKMREsLs3h8Yo8PfVMxqltqAdRb2IA5h6ARlfqGpf6hpfrD5Fw)):

```py
from itertools import pairwise
import random
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left
from time import perf_counter as time
from statistics import mean, stdev


def partition_original(values, thresholds):
    """ Partition values into a list of sets 
        with values in right-open intervals specified by thresholds.
    """
    return [ { v for v in values if v < thresholds[0] }
       ] + [ { v for v in values if lo <= v < hi }
                                for lo, hi in tuple(pairwise(thresholds))
       ] + [ { v for v in values if thresholds[-1] <= v } ]


def partition_Kelly(values, thresholds):
    res = [set() for _ in thresholds]
    res.append(set())
    for v in values:
        i = bisect(thresholds, v)
        res[i].add(v)
    return res


def partition_Kelly2(values, thresholds):
    res = [set() for _ in thresholds]
    res.append(set())
    for v in set(values):
        i = bisect(thresholds, v)
        res[i].add(v)
    return res


def partition_Kelly3(values, thresholds):
    def partition(values, thresholds):
        if not thresholds:
            return [set(values)]
        i = len(thresholds) // 2
        threshold = thresholds[i]
        hi = []
        lo = [x for x in values if x < threshold or hi.append(x)]
        return partition(lo, thresholds[:i]) + partition(hi, thresholds[i+1:])
    return partition(set(values), thresholds)


def partition_Kelly3b(values, thresholds):
    def partition(values, thresholds):
        if not thresholds:
            return [set(values)]
        i = len(thresholds) // 2
        threshold = thresholds[i]
        hi = [].append
        lo = [x for x in values if x < threshold or hi(x)]
        return partition(lo, thresholds[:i]) + partition(hi.__self__, thresholds[i+1:])
    return partition(set(values), thresholds)


def partition_Kelly4(values, thresholds):
    values = sorted(set(values))
    res = []
    i = 0
    for threshold in thresholds:
        j = bisect_left(values, threshold)
        res.append(set(values[i:j]))
        i = j
    res.append(set(values[i:]))
    return res


def partition_Kelly4a(values, thresholds):
    values = sorted(set(values))
    res = []
    i = 0
    for threshold in thresholds:
        j = bisect_left(values, threshold, i)
        res.append(set(values[i:j]))
        i = j
    res.append(set(values[i:]))
    return res


def partition_Kelly4b(values, thresholds):
    values = sorted(values)
    res = []
    i = 0
    for threshold in thresholds:
        j = bisect_left(values, threshold)
        res.append(set(values[i:j]))
        i = j
    res.append(set(values[i:]))
    return res


def partition_Kelly4c(values, thresholds):
    def partition(start, stop, thresholds):
        if not thresholds:
            return [set(values[start:stop])]
        i = len(thresholds) // 2
        threshold = thresholds[i]
        j = bisect_left(values, threshold, start, stop)
        return partition(start, j, thresholds[:i]) + partition(j, stop, thresholds[i+1:])
    values = sorted(set(values))
    return partition(0, len(values), thresholds)


def partition_dankal444(values, thresholds):
    import bisect
    sets = [set() for _ in range(len(thresholds) + 1)]

    for value in values:
        set_idx = bisect.bisect_left(thresholds, value)
        sets[set_idx].add(value)
    return sets


funcs = [partition_original, partition_Kelly, partition_Kelly2, partition_Kelly3, partition_Kelly3b, partition_Kelly4, partition_Kelly4a, partition_Kelly4b, partition_Kelly4c, partition_dankal444]
wrong = set()

def test(n, k, repeat):
    print(n, 'values and', k, 'thresholds:')
    t0 = time()

    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(repeat):
        values = random.choices(range(n), k=n)
        thresholds = [int((i+.5)/k * n) for i in range(k)]
        expect = none = object()
        for f in funcs:
            t = time()
            result = f(values, thresholds)
            times[f].append(time() - t)
            if expect is none:
                expect = result
            elif result != expect:
                wrong.add(f)
        funcs[:] = [f for f in funcs if f not in wrong]

    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

    print()#time() - t0)

test(10**4, 3, 100)
test(10**4, 10, 80)
test(10**4, 10**2, 25)
print('Wrong:')
for f in wrong:
    print(' ', f.__name__)
```

Comment: I think Kelly3/b really cute.

Comment: I suspect that Kelly4b is relatively simple to accelerate with Numba

Answer (score -1):

Using  `bisect.bisect_left` function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left))

```
import bisect
sets = [set() for _ in range(len(thresholds) + 1)]

for value in values:
    set_idx = bisect.bisect_left(thresholds, value)
    sets[set_idx].add(value)
```

Note it might be slower for some sizes of values/thresholds. Larger the sizes performance should get better compared to OP method (`O(nlogn)` vs `O(n^2)`)

Comment: For *n* items, *k* thresholds: O(*n*log*k*) vs. O(*nk*). The application that triggered this question had k=3…

Comment: @greybeard oh yes, you are right, I oversimplified this big O notation.